# Setting Button text programmatically is automatically going to last Index

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-button

So I'm working on an Android app, and trying to add buttons that will have click-triggered `Dialog`s programmatically.

When I add the `OnClickListener` to these buttons, I'm either getting the text from the last `Button` added, an error claiming that there is an IOOBException when calling tv1.setText(...) - invalid index 7, size is 7, or just nothing passed. Does anybody have any idea how I can set each `Button` to create a new `Dialog` with unique information for each button?

Snippet of code that's posing the problem:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_streaks);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("carter.streakly", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    mTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.all_streak_table);
    res = db.getAllData();
    if(res.getCount() ==0) {
        //show message
        showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
        return;
    }

    streakArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    int counter = 0;
    while (res.moveToNext()){
        streakArrayList.add(new Streak(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(0)), res.getString(1), res.getString(2), res.getString(3), Integer.parseInt(res.getString(4))));
        counter++;
    }

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
    btnParams.setMargins(200, 30, 80, 30);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);

    i = 0;
    while (i < counter){
        if(i%2==0){
            mTableRow = new TableRow(this);
            mTableLayout.addView(mTableRow);
        }

        ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mTableRow.addView(ll);

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText(""+streakArrayList.get(i).getDaysKept());
        btn.setId(i);
        btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button));
        btn.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AllStreaks.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_enlarged);

                tv1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.activity_enlarge_icon);
                tv1.setText(streakArrayList.get(i-1).getActivityName());
                dialog.show();
                /*
                Intent intent = new Intent(AllStreaks.this, EnlargedActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("passName", streakArrayList.get(view.getId()).getActivityName());
                startActivity(intent);*/
            }
        });

        ll.addView(btn);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityName());
        tv.setId(i);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        tv.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
        ll.addView(tv);

        i++;
    }
}

public void showMessage(String title, String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: Can you call `res.moveToFirst()` before calculating your counter?

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate at all? Where should I call res.moveToFirst() and why? Thank you!!

Comment: Add moveToFirst just after you have counter = 0 before your while loop.

Comment: Why is the index `i-1` in `tv1.setText(streakArrayList.get(i-1).getActivityName());` inside `onClick()`?

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code.

First of all, you're using a global instance of both your `TableRow` and `LinearLayout`. This means you overwrite them on every iteration of your loop, so in the end only the values from the last iteration will be visible.

You're giving the same ID to both your `Button` and your `TextView`, they should be unique.

Using the `counter` variable is completely unnecessary, you could just use a for loop to iterate through your `streakArrayList`.

Something like this:

```
for (Streak streak : streakArrayList) {
    TableRow mTableRow = new TableRow(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final String activityName = streak.getActivityName();

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("" + streak.getDaysKept());
    btn.setId(aUniqueId);
    btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button));
    btn.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AllStreaks.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_enlarged);

            tv1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.activity_enlarge_icon);
            tv1.setText(activityName);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(activityName);
    tv.setId(anotherUniqueId);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    tv.setLayoutParams(tvParams);

    ll.addView(btn);
    ll.addView(tv);

    mTableRow.addView(ll);
    mTableLayout.addView(mTableRow);
}
```